# How can I reformat tabular data using AWK?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file contain following output.

```
ora.abc.db
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       serverA              Open
      2        ONLINE  ONLINE       serverB              Open
ora.xyz.db
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       serverA              Open
      2        ONLINE  ONLINE       serverB              Open
      2        ONLINE  ONLINE       serverC              Open
```

I want to format this file in following way, but i want to use `shell script` only, I believe we can use awk but i don't have logic

```
abc  abc1  ONLINE serverA
abc  abc2  ONLINE serverB
xyz  xyz1  ONLINE serverA
xyz  xyz2  ONLINE serverB
xyz  xyz3  ONLINE serverC
```

Comment: What is the problem? Write the script.

Comment: I suspect there is a typo, and you want the third line in `ora.xyz.db` to begin with the number `3`, right?

Comment: How is one of the two ONLINE's in every line discarded?

Comment: It is not clear if the word in the second column ("ONLINE") or the third column ("ONLINE") needs to be echoed. Nor whether anything should change in the output depending on whether the last column is "Open".

Comment: ONLINE from second column field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be an aproach:

```
$ awk '/^ora/ {split($0,a,"."); next} {print a[2], a[2]$1, $2, $4}' a
abc abc1 ONLINE serverA
abc abc2 ONLINE serverB
xyz xyz1 ONLINE serverA
xyz xyz2 ONLINE serverB
xyz xyz2 ONLINE serverC
```

#### Explanation

- `/^ora/` applies for lines starting with `ora`. In those, `split` the content based on the dot `.` and store it in the array `a`. So it is `a[1]=ora`, `a[2]=abc`, ... Then `next` makes `awk` jump to next line.
- `print` prints the 2nd field of the array `a` plus different elements from the line: `$1` stating for the first, `$4` stating for the 4th.

Comment: I am not AWK expert so could you please explain your syntax?

Comment: @Satish sure, done! :)

Comment: Freaking awesome logic, you rocks!!

Answer (score 4):

A slightly expanded (but largely equivalent) script:

```
{
if($0 ~ /^ora/)  {         # look for lines starting (^) with "ora"
    split($0, temp, ".");  # find the elements of the line an put in array
    serverName = temp[2];  # the "middle bit" - what was found between two dots
    next;                  # nothing else to do with this line
  }
else  {
    print serverName, serverName$1, $3, $4; # string together the bits
    # note that each $n corresponds to the nth "word"
    # by default fields are separated by white space
    # you can set the variable FS to something else (e.g. FS=",")
    # to deal with other formate
  }
}
```

Put this in a file `server.awk`, and if your input is in `log.txt`, invoke it with

```
awk -f server.awk log.txt
```

I hope the explanation adds some value...

Comment: Cool man!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!